# Why is the code inside the method executed twice?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

The code inside the `CustomerRepository.GetCustomers()` method is executed twice.
Why is this happening?
 
In the picture, I showed the steps for executing the code  inside the method.

**Description.**
The code comes in step "5".
After step "5" the code goes to step "6".
After step "11" the debugger continues to work according to the code.

---

**Picture-1**
[image]

**Picture-2**
[image]

**Picture-3**
[image]

---

**Program.cs**

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleAppCore
{
    class Program
    {   
        static async Task Main(string[] args) // ++ 
        {
            // await TestMain();

            Test1 test1 = new Test1();
            await test1.TestMain();
        }       
    }
}
```

**Test1.cs**

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

// 
using NUnit.Framework;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

//
using ConsoleApp;
using ConsoleApp.Model;
using DBRepository.Interfaces;
using DBRepository.Repositories;
using DBRepository.Factories;

namespace ConsoleAppCore
{
    // NUnit тестирование 
    // пишем классы с атрибутом [TestFixture] 
    // пишем методы с атрибутом [Test] 
    [TestFixture]
    public class Test1
    {
        public Test1()
        {
            TestMain();
        }

        public Task TestMain()
        {            
            return GetCustomersTest_1();
        }       

        /// <summary>
        /// ____
        /// </summary>
        [TestMethod]
        public async Task GetCustomersTest_1()
        {
            SettingsService settingsService = new SettingsService();
            Settings settings = new Settings();

            // Получить строку подключения
            settings = settingsService.ReadFilfeT();
            string connectionString = settings.ConnectionString;

            IRepositoryContextFactory _iRepositoryContextFactory = new RepositoryContextFactory();
            ICustomerRepository _iCustomerRepository = new CustomerRepository(connectionString, _iRepositoryContextFactory);

            var customerList = await _iCustomerRepository.GetCustomers();
            string strTest = "";
        }
    }
```

**CustomerRepository.cs**

```
using DBRepository.Interfaces;
using Models;

// 
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Collections.Generic;



namespace DBRepository.Repositories
{
    public class CustomerRepository : BaseRepository, ICustomerRepository
    {
        // Constructor
        public CustomerRepository(string connectionString, IRepositoryContextFactory contextFactory) : base(connectionString, contextFactory)
        {

        }

        public async Task<List<Customer>> GetCustomers()
        {
            using (var context = ContextFactory.CreateDbContext(ConnectionString))
            {
                var query = context.Customers.AsQueryable();
                    query = query.Where(p => p.ContactName.Contains("Maria"));
                return await query.ToListAsync();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in your test code.
You're executing the `TestMain` twice from the `Program.cs`.
Note, that the `Test1` constructor already calls the `TestMain` method internally. And after that's done, you call it one more time manually.
Given that you call the `TestMain` manually once, no need to call it from the `Test1` constructor:

```cs
[TestFixture]
    public class Test1
    {
        public Test1()
        {
            // Commenting this out.
            //TestMain();
        }

        public Task TestMain()
        {            
            return GetCustomersTest_1();
        }    
        //...
```

Hope this helps